# I want to find a query for mysql such that query = answer then sleep for some seconds

Tags: sql, mysql, syntax-error, sql-injection

I have Queried my database(MYSQL) as:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables LIMIT 1;
```

Which result in 21 columns so:

```
SELECT tabel_name,NULL,NULL(x18 times more) FROM information_schema.tables LIMIT 1;
```

Which returns answer as:

```
customers,NULL,NULL(x18 more times)
```

Now I want to write a query such that if the case is true the page should sleep for 10 seconds:

```
SELECT IF(SELECT table_name,NULL,NULL(x18 times more) FROM information_schema.tables LIMIT 1; = 'customers,NULL,NULL(x18 more times)',SLEEP(5),'a');
```

But it returns error incorrect syntax

can someone please let me know what could be a possible correct syntax to achieve desired result

I tried adding and removing '' around result

removing select statement for the first query

and changing it into union select query

I am a Beginner and so forgive me for any noob mistake and any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Semi-colon terminates the query.  When you have an embedded query, you don't use the semi-colon.   Put the embedded SELECT in a set of parentheses.   What you are doing here is not normal.  What's the purpose?  What are you using to query the database?  Is there a program involved?

Comment: I have trying to find  a query that enumerates table name in a blind sql injection setup and it is a black box setup